# Elixir: IEx.pry error: IEx shell running?

Tags: elixir

On Elixir Sips 33 - Pry:

While I'm trying to use IEx.pry, I have something basic like this:

```
require IEx

defmodule IexPryTest do

  def add(a, b) do
    c = a + b
    IEx.pry
    c
  end
end
```

I get this Pry error:

```
iex(1)> IexPryTest.add(1, 2)
Cannot pry #PID<0.88.0> at lib/iex_pry_test.ex:24. Is an IEx shell running?
```

I think iex is running, since thats where I'm running this from.

I'm on Windows 8.1 if that makes any difference.

Any suggestions to get Pry running?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried on a Windows 7 VM from the standard command prompt, and this definitely seems like a bug. Perhaps you could open an issue on elixir-lang GitHub?

However, when starting the GUI shell with `iex --werl`, pry worked. Can you try that one?

Comment: Yup, you need the --werl option in Windows. I wonder if we should add wiex on Windows and leave iex as a fallback.

Comment: In any case, we need to fix the error message. It could be clearer. :)